# Most elegant way to pass props into card details from DB with subdirectory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

**I have a card with an info button rendered from cards.js. Once clicked the page should be rendering from a JSON format:**

```
import React from "react";
import stylecard from "./Cards.module.css";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
//import * as FaIcons from "react-icons/fc";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Cardpage from "../Cardpage";



const Cards = () => {
  //TODO Import database in Alley or pull in centrally
  const NFTDatabase = [
    {
      img: "https://openseauserdata.com/files/zoonies_featured_image_4Z8jsfR.jpg",
      title: "BAG COllection ",
      description:
        "I tailored this bag of NFTs from my personal favorite collection. As a bonus I've added a BAYC Ape ...",
      price: "1 ETH",
      id: "B8dj8398jdlls"
    },
    {
      img: "https://openseauserdata.com/files/zoonies_featured_image_4Z8jsfR.jpg",
      title: "BAG COLLECTION ",
      description:
        "I tailored this bag of NFTs from my personal favorite collection. As a bonus I've added a BAYC Ape ...",
      price: "1 ETH",
      id: "3ppqYfl7xZ69"
    },
    {
      img: "https://openseauserdata.com/files/zoonies_featured_image_4Z8jsfR.jpg",
      title: "NFT APE",
      description: "BLABLABLA NFT WAUWIE",
      price: "1 ETH",
      id: "GnTnJ55015lh"
    },
    {
      img: "https://openseauserdata.com/files/zoonies_featured_image_4Z8jsfR.jpg",
      title: "NFT APE",
      description: "BLABLABLA NFT WAUWIE",
      price: "1 ETH",
      id: "B6a84845s4df56ae"
    },
    {
      img: "https://openseauserdata.com/files/zoonies_featured_image_4Z8jsfR.jpg",
      title: "NFT APE",
      description: "BLABLABLA NFT WAUWIE",
      price: "1 ETH",
      id: "X50O4jpYob15"
    },
    {
      img: "https://openseauserdata.com/files/zoonies_featured_image_4Z8jsfR.jpg",
      title: "NFT APE",
      description: "BLABLABLA NFT WAUWIE",
      price: "1 ETH",
      id: "089FEs9fbfq7"
    },
    {
      img: "https://openseauserdata.com/files/zoonies_featured_image_4Z8jsfR.jpg",
      title: "NFT APE",
      description: "BLABLABLA NFT WAUWIE",
      price: "1 ETH",
      id: "8Y9FTUL4q9N2"
    },
    {
      img: "https://openseauserdata.com/files/zoonies_featured_image_4Z8jsfR.jpg",
      title: "NFT APE",
      description: "BLABLABLA NFT WAUWIE",
      price: "1 ETH",
      id: "XFe8h3g49g8I"
    },
  ];
  

  
 


  const renderCard = (props, index) => {
    console.log(props)
    console.log(index)
   
    return (
      <Card style={{ margin: "1rem", width: "23rem" }} key={props.id}>
        <Card.Header
          style={{
            backgroundImage:
              "linear-gradient(144deg,#AF40FF, #5B42F3 50%,#00DDEB)",
          }}
        ></Card.Header>
        <div
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-evenly",
            margin: "10px",
          }}
        >
          <Card.Img
            top
            src={props.img}
            alt={props.title}
            style={{ borderRadius: 9999, width: "9.5rem", margin: "10px" }}
          />
          <Card.Img
            top
            src={props.img}
            alt={props.title}
            style={{ borderRadius: 9999, width: "9.5rem", margin: "10px" }}
          />
          <Card.Img
            top
            src={props.img}
            alt={props.title}
            style={{ borderRadius: 9999, width: "9.5rem", margin: "10px" }}
          />
          <Card.Img
            top
            src={props.img}
            alt={props.title}
            style={{ borderRadius: 9999, width: "9.5rem", margin: "10px" }}
          />
        </div>

        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title
            style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
            tag="h5"
          >
            {props.title} #{index + 1}
          </Card.Title>
          <Card.Subtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">
            {props.title}{" "}
            {props.id}
          </Card.Subtitle>
          <Card.Text style={{ fontSize: "12px" }} tag="h6">
            {props.description}
          </Card.Text>
          <div className="flex-wrapper" style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', display:'flex' }}>
            <Button
              style={{
                backgroundImage:
                  "linear-gradient(144deg,#AF40FF, #5B42F3 50%,#00DDEB)",
                  width:'10rem'
                  
              }}
            >
              Buy
            </Button>
            <Button
              style={{
                backgroundImage:
                  "linear-gradient(144deg,#AF40FF, #5B42F3 50%,#00DDEB)",
                  width:'10rem'
              }}
            >
              <Link to="Cardpage/" style={{color:'white', textDecoration:'none'}} props={props}> Info </Link>
              
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
        <Card.Footer></Card.Footer>
      </Card>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="grid"
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
      }}
      xs={12}
      md={3}
      xl={1}
    >
      {NFTDatabase.map(renderCard)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

**So, this renders a page with n amount of cards depending on the size of the dataset. And then my Cardpage.js. I'm trying to get the same card.id from the card as key such that I render all items in bag_NFTs based on that card.id**

```
import React from "react";

import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";


const Cardpage = (props) => {

    const Collectionbag = [
        {
            id : 'B8dj8398jdlls',
            num_NFTs: '19',
            price : '10',
            bag_NFTs: [{
                id: "Lm1EWCRy7q9V",
                name: "Some NFT 1",
                price: '1',
                img: "https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/awesome-bored-ape-glass-eye-nft-style_361671-269.jpg?w=2000",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "6pX1cP39BtERL",
                name: "Some NFT 2",
                price: '1',
                img: "https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/KXYdqZD1-HDCn1ltZdb2rIlLOuw=/1400x1400/filters:format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/23603505/VRG_Illo_5265_M_Li_NFT_explainer.jpg",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "26VAZHRxM1rn",
                name: "Some NFT 3",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "otq82x47Qp2q",
                name: "Some NFT 4",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            
            {
                id: "SeA644L1KWUg",
                name: "Some NFT 5",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "85arAdYK1p4U",
                name: "Some NFT 6",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "xL9FWZR6tQ5re",
                name: "Some NFT 7",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "77Y89D53IybL",
                name: "Some NFT 8",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "mBHT2B00Qwrd",
                name: "Some NFT 9",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "19L5I343ldDp",
                name: "Some NFT 10",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"}]
            },
        {
            id : '3423dasdddls',
            num_NFTs: '2',
            price : '150',
            bag_NFTs: [{
                id: "837OeQ3iy1YI",
                name: "Some NFT 1 of other",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"},
            {
                id: "9enWRL959xfk",
                name: "Some NFT 2 of other",
                price: '1',
                img: "",
                address: "xF0515d1a56sd1fd1dfasdfedaaf453454D"}]
            },
    ]


    const renderSingleBag = (props, index) => {

        const child_props = props.bag_NFTs

        return (

  
            <div style={{ margin: "4rem", width: "92rem"}} >
                <Card key={child_props.id}>
                <Card.Header>
                    This is the header
                </Card.Header>
               
                <Card.Body>
                <div>
                    <Card.Img 
                    src={child_props.img}
                    alt={child_props.name}
                    style={{ borderRadius: 9999, width: "9.5rem", margin: "10px" }}>

                    </Card.Img>
                </div>
                    {child_props.address}
                </Card.Body>
                <Card.Footer>

                </Card.Footer>
            </Card>

            </div>
        )};

    return (

        <div props={props}> {Collectionbag.map(renderSingleBag)}</div>
    )
};

export default Cardpage;
```

**My App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }}>
      
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>} ></Route>
          <Route path="alley" element={<Alley />} ></Route>
          <Route path="bag" element={<Bag />} ></Route>
          <Route path="View" element={<View/>} ></Route>
          <Route path="/Alley/Cardpage" element={<Cardpage/>} ></Route>
        </Routes>
        
      </Layout>
    </div>
    );
}
```

I think there's a more efficient way, and I've tried a lot of things, but couldn't get the Cardpage rendered.

Comment: You've some *oddly* implemented components. Can you clarify what "couldn't get the Cardpage rendered" means? Like the `"/Alley/Cardpage"` route isn't matched and rendering `CardPage`? Or it is and `CardPage` has an issue rendering something? The post isn't very clear on what the issue is.

Comment: In my button in my Cards.js I pass a props in my `<Link to="Cardpage/" props={props}> Info </Link>` to render card details with `renderSingleBag` stored in Cardpage.js . I then attempt to pass the props.id into Cardpage to show all unique items given the props.id with `<div props={props}> {Collectionbag.map(renderSingleBag)}</div>` . I just want a info button that navigates to a second page that shows all items associated with the card with the info button. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: The `Link` component doesn't consume any `props` prop. Are you trying to link to `CardPage` with a specific card id, i.e. something like ```<Link to={`Cardpage/${props.id}`}>Info</Link>``` and `path="/Alley/Cardpage/:cardId"`, or pass it in route state like ```<Link to="Cardpage" state={{ cardId: props.id }}>Info</Link>```?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to link to `Cardpage`  with the specific `card.id` of the card when clicking on the button. Passing the `card.id` should render all items from a JSON array that lists multiple items for every `card.id`. Those items consist of `id` `num_NFTS` `price` and `bag_NFTS`, and I try to iterate over` bag_NFTs` that returns `id` `name` `price` `img` `address` as `props.id` `props.name` .... as input for my `card` parameter in `renderSingleBag` in Cardpage.js.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: [link]https://codesandbox.io/embed/misty-glade-mutqnf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark I hope this works.

Comment: It works, sort of. It seems there are some import export issues with some components. The `MetaMask` can't be imported since there's no `BlockChain` directory. Is the sandbox actually running for you?

Comment: I've ommitted that map as it's not functional right now. You can delete that import. The sandbox is not actually running for me...it's running locally fine.